# No module named ‘application’` when deploying to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a django project on elastic beanstalk, I have used this AWS official Doc for django deployment on EB:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

These are Steps i followed:

1. eb init
2. eb create
3. put CNAME in ALLOWED_HOST
4. eb deploy

and when i try to see my website, i get ERROR: "502 Bad Gateway: nginx"
So i checked web.stdout.log file and found this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrWBO.png

This is my django.config file (present in .ebextensions folder)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPXnS.png

This is my directory structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZzcG.png

This is my wsgi.py file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl6gs.png

I want to solve this error. I don't know what's the problem, and I really need someone to help me solve this error, Your help means a lot to me. if you need any additional information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you were able to solve this. But have you tried updating the wsgi path in .ebextensions
For Python Flask I had to make it as -

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: application:application
```

Also, you can check the configuration in AWS EB console, the wsgi path mentioned there should also be the correct one.